# Управление паролями в Linux

Tags: linux

Помогите решить задачу.

Для new_user требуется задать пароль qwerty, который должен устареть через 42 дня. Напишите синтаксис команды (сам пароль в поле ответа вводить не требуется). Действия должны выполняться в контексте root с использованием &&

я пробовал написать так, но система ответ не принимает:

***passwd new_user && chage -W 42 new_user***

Comment: А зачем использовать chage, если у команды passwd тоже есть опции `-W` / `-M`

Comment: @andreymal в смысле команда должна быть такой: passwd new_user && passwd -W 42 new_user

Comment: А зачем использовать passwd два раза?

Comment: А, в условии написано «использованием &&»... ну блин, тупое какое-то условие :(

Comment: как паписать правильно?

Comment: у тебя вопрос примерно звучит "задать пароль, который устареет через указанное количество дней". Почему ты в заголовке пишешь "Управление паролями", что совсем не отражает твоей проблемы??

Answer (score 0):

Должна подойти следующая команда: **passwd new_user && chage -M 42 new_user**

Флаг -W, --warndays WARN_DAYS устанавливает количество дней, с которых пользователю начнет выводиться предупреждение об истечении срока действия его пароля и необходимости его изменения. 
Нужен флаг -M, --maxdays MAX_DAYS, который устанавливает максимальное количество дней между сменами пароля.

Comment: предложенный вариант Не подходит

Comment: Я попробовал у себя, оно работает. Как ты определяешь, что оно не работает? Правда, "qwerty" нужно ввести интерактивно.

Comment: Может помочь команда **echo -e "qwerty\nqwerty\n" | passwd sasha && chage -M 42 sasha**, если ты хочешь избавиться от интерактивного ввода. Так же я предполагаю, что ты выполняешь это под рутом. Если нет, то нужно будет добавить sudo: "sudo passwd ..." и "sudo chage ..."

Comment: Обучаюсь в SkillFactory. После каждого задания есть окошко куда нужно ввести ответ, сисетма проверяет правильно или нет. Я все на компе делал у меня получалось. Не понимаю логики проверки ответов, чего может не хватать.

Comment: Ну, тогда я не могу больше ничего придумать. Можешь попробовать вариант выше с **echo** или вариант с **sudo**: **sudo passwd new_user && sudo chage -M 42 new_user**. P.s. в варианте с **echo** поставь правильное имя юзера (я своё поставил, пока у себя тестил).

Comment: @SinelnikovAlexander, спасибо за настоящее имя, осталось только хакерам пароль подобрать, хотя может так покажете?

Comment: @0andriy Под своим именем я имел в виду своё тестовое, разумеется.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo passwd new_user && passwd -x 42 new_user
```

Comment: А в этом курсе еще не проходили команду man? Тогда попробуйте `man passwd`. Изучаете эту справку, находите нужный параметр. Аналогично `man chage`.

Comment: man проходили самой первой, просто некоторые задания, которые предельно просты, имеют условия со звездочкой. И выполнить надо именно так как я описал, тот же chage использовать нельзя

Answer (score 0):

```
passwd -p new_user && chage -i 42 new_user
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: По сути это дубликат старого [ответа от Александра Синельникова](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1438730/386633), ухудшенный вариант без комментариев.